# Arguments and positional parameters in `bash -c <some-command>`

Tags: bash

Bash Manual says about `bash -c <some-command>`:

> Read and execute commands from **the first non-option argument after processing the options**, then exit. **Any remaining arguments are assigned to the
>   positional parameters, starting with $0.**

What do the following mean:

- "the first non-option argument after processing the options"
- "Any remaining arguments are assigned to the
  positional parameters, starting with `$0`"

In the second one, are the positional parameters for `bash` or for `some-command`?

Answer (score 3):

> "the first non-option argument after processing the options"

This is talking about options to your invocation of `bash`.  `-c`, for example, is an option you're applying to `bash` in your example that would not be sent to any command you're invoking.

> "Any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`"

What this means, is that if you execute `bash -c /path/to/script arg1 arg2`, the specified script will be executed with `/path/to/script`, `arg1`, and `arg2` being assigned to the positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, and `$2` respectively, just as though you had run the command in an interactive `bash` session.